# Longtable and page break

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I'm writing the use case documentation for my Software Engineering project. I'm using `longtable` to get a template that spans over multiple pages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used to produce long text
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.74\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
        \hline
        \textbf{ID}                & \texttt{UC\_01\_01}            \\
        \textbf{Name}              & Password recovery              \\
        \textbf{\textit{Macro}-UC} & Registration (\texttt{UC\_01}) \\
        \textbf{Actors}            & \texttt{ACTOR\_02}             \\ \hline
        \textbf{Preconditions}     & \lipsum[2-4]                   \\ \hline
        \textbf{Main flow}         & Some itemize list here!        \\ \hline
        \textbf{Postconditions}    & \lipsum[5-7]                   \\ \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the table doesn't break within the row. I would need a breakable content to put into a row to have a homogeneous filling on each page.

I tried to wrap this row in a box using the `framed` package but it doesn't work. I noticed that I can achieve a break page within a box with the `mdframed` package but I can't use it since I'm working on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/) and I've no version of LaTeX installed on my computer.

I've also tried the `usecase` package but it doesn't support page breaking.

Could you please suggest me a trick or an alternative to achieve this result? I've been stucking on this matter for two days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with longtable, or any other tabular environment for that matter, because the material inside the tabular cells are TeX boxes, which by definition cannot be broken.

I suggest you use `parcolumns` instead, which has been designed to typeset several columns next to each other for multilingual texts. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used to produce long text
\usepackage{parcolumns}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[colwidths={2=0.74\textwidth},rulebetween,sloppy]{2}
    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{ID}}
    \colchunk[2]{\texttt{UC\_01\_01}}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{Name}}
    \colchunk[2]{Password recovery}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{\textit{Macro}-UC}}
    \colchunk[2]{Registration (\texttt{UC\_01})}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{Actors}}
    \colchunk[2]{\texttt{ACTOR\_02}}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{Preconditions}}
    \colchunk[2]{\lipsum[2-4]}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{Main flow}}
    \colchunk[2]{Some itemize list here!}
    \colplacechunks

    \colchunk[1]{\textbf{Postconditions}}
    \colchunk[2]{\lipsum[5-9]}
    \colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @alexraasch! Your example helps me a lot! Just a couple of questions: 1. How can I add a blank line before and after the main flow chunk to make it more readable? 2. Is there an option that allows me to reduce (or remove) the indentation inside the two columns?

Comment: 1. `\colchunk[1]{~\\\textbf{Main flow}\\}` and `\colchunk[2]{~\\Some itemize list here!\\}`. Can't think of something more elegant right now. :) 2. Put the `distance=...` option in the square brackets. Default is `2em`.

Answer (score 2):

Just to record `parallel` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Used to produce long text
\usepackage{parallel}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{0.4\textwidth}{0.55\textwidth}
    \ParallelLText{\textbf{ID}}
    \ParallelRText{\texttt{UC\_01\_01}}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{Name}}
    \ParallelRText{Password recovery}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{\textit{Macro}-UC}}
    \ParallelRText{Registration (\texttt{UC\_01})}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{Actors}}
    \ParallelRText{\texttt{ACTOR\_02}}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{Preconditions}}
    \ParallelRText{\lipsum[2-4]}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{Main flow}}
    \ParallelRText{Some itemize list here!}
    \ParallelPar

    \ParallelLText{\textbf{Postconditions}}
    \ParallelRText{\lipsum[5-9]}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```